# Primary key violation with new duplicate objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 with a code first approach.

I have two classes that have a many-to-many relationship to each other, `Movie` and `Person`. A `Movie` is related to a `Person` via a `Character`. Each `Movie` can have multiple characters.

```
public class Movie {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; } 

    public Movie() {
        Characters = new HashSet<Character>();
    }
}

public class Character {
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }    
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }

    public Person() {
        Characters = new HashSet<Character>();
    }
}
```

Sometimes a `Movie` can have one `Person` that plays more than one `Character`.  I'm running into a problem when trying to add a `Movie` under this circumstance...

Let's say Movie1 has 2 characters both played by Person1. When saving changes EF will start at Character1 and see that Person1 doesn't exist in the database and insert that `Person` to `dbo.Person`. Then it will go to Character2 but see that Person1 already exists and will throw a primary key violation.

In my `MovieRepository` I have an `Add(Movie entity)` method. I loop through each `Character` of the `Movie` and check to see if the related `Person` exists in the database. If they do then I set the `Person` property to the existing `Person`. This works under normal cases but if the `Person` doesn't exist at all then I'm not sure how to avoid the PK violation, and this is my problem :)

```
public class MovieRepository : Repository<Movie> {
    public MovieRepository(MovieContext context) : base(context) {}

    public override void Add(Movie entity) {
        foreach (var character in entity.Characters) {
            var person = Context.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == character.Person.Id);
            if (person != null)
                character.Person = person;
        }
        Context.Movies.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Just to add a little more info. I'm using the Repository Pattern with the Unit Of Work pattern to hold my Repositories and Context. So the `UnitOfWork` class is responsible for `SaveChanges()`.

Trying to do this in the `MovieRepository.Add()` may not be the best/appropriate way to accomplish this task. I look forward to any and all suggestions.

Just for further clarification I am getting my data from the Rotten Tomatoes API and the json looks something like this...

```
{data : [{
    Id: 12345,
    Title: 'Movie1',
    Year: 2010,
    Character: [{
        Name: 'Character1',
        Person: { Id: 1, Name: 'Person1' }
    },{
        Name: 'Character2',
        Person: { Id: 2, Name: 'Person2' }
    }]
}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you sending in the same person object for 2 characters? Does it already have a unique key set? otherwise they will be seen as two separate objects by the Entity Framework. If you already have a unique key defined you could simply check the Local collection first, then context or else add the person to the context.

```
// Only works if the unique key is already defined.
var person =
    Context.People.Local.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == character.Person.Id) ??
    Context.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == character.Person.Id);

if (person == null)
    Context.People.Add(person);
```

However I would suggest possibly changing your aggregates so that this method does not add people at all. You could treat adding a person and adding a 'Movie" (as an aggregate of {Movie, Character} as 2 separate operations. This would make sense if you manage people separately (such that a person can have zero or many characters).

This would make more sense since the Movie does not "own" the people, it is a many to many relation.

For example in the UI: When adding a movie with characters you get to chose the person who played the character, or at this point add a new one. Thus when sending the movie to be saved you will always have a character.PersonId which will point to the person object which has already been saved.

Though of course this may not work for your particular scenario, just an idea.

Comment: Yes the unique key for `Person` is already set. The data is coming from the Rotten Tomatoes API. I updated my question above to include a sample of the json that I am serializing and trying to save in the db.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly this only occurs when:

1. The person did not previously exist in the DB
2. The person plays more than one character in the Movie?

More explicitly, Do you have the same failure if a Person who already exists in the DB plays two Characters in a Movie?

It sounds like you may need to ensure you persist (save) a new person before using them a second time?

Something like:

```
public class MovieRepository : Repository<Movie> {
public MovieRepository(MovieContext context) : base(context) {}

public override void Add(Movie entity) {
    foreach (var character in entity.Characters) {
        var person = Context.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == character.Person.Id);
        if (person != null) {
            character.Person = person;
        } else {
            personRepository.Save(character.Person)
        }
    }
    Context.Movies.Add(entity);
}
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. Are u suggesting I `SaveChanges()` on the context for every new `Person`? If so, wouldn't that be inefficient?

Comment: I suppose there might be a performance hit to it, over 'batching' them, but I doubt it would be significant. I would try it and address a performance problem if it arises.

Comment: Just noted the Context.Repo.Local. lookup, this is where some experience in EF (which I am still learning) helps. I have done a lot more work in Java/Hibernate. I was unable to comment above but that fixes your concern with my approach completely. Thanks Brent!